# Select * from subquery

Tags: sql, oracle

I'd like to get sum of column1, sum of column2 and total sum. In Postgres I can do it this way: **(notice the star)**

```
SELECT *, a+b AS total_sum FROM
(
   SELECT SUM(column1) AS a, SUM(column2) AS b
   FROM table
)
```

But in Oracle I get an syntax error and have to use this:

```
SELECT a,b, a+b AS total_sum FROM
(
   SELECT SUM(column1) AS a, SUM(column2) AS b
   FROM table
)
```

I have really lot of columns to return so I do not want to write the column names again in the main query. Is there any easy solution?

I cannot use a+b in the inner query because there are not known at this place.
I do not want to use `SELECT SELECT SUM(column1) AS a, SUM(column2) AS b, SUM(column1)+SUM(column2) AS total_sum`.

Comment: `SELECT SUM(col1) AS a, SUM(col2) AS b, SUM(col1) + SUM(col2) AS total_sum FROM table`?

Answer (score 186, accepted):

You can select every column from that sub-query by aliasing it and adding the alias before the `*`:

```
SELECT t.*, a+b AS total_sum
FROM
(
   SELECT SUM(column1) AS a, SUM(column2) AS b
   FROM table
) t
```

Comment: Works for DB2 as well

Comment: what is this called? to form a table using subqueries and how can we optimise such nested sub queries?

Comment: @VishalParkash: This is called a _derived table_.

Comment: @PeterLang and what about optimisation?